# Where can I find good python Twisted framework documentation, blog entries, articles, etc?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm playing around with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) and documentation found on their homepage doesn't answer all my questions.

The topic I am most interested at the moment is Twisted Application Framework. Also some open source servers using twisted framework would provide nice material for studying how it's all tied up together in a bigger project.

So far I've checked out iCal and read documentation on twisted website (3x) and few good articles I found in google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The published book is pretty useless, in my opinion.

I recommend starting with the "deferred" docs online, and making absolutely sure you understand what asynchronous means and what deferreds are for.  The best online docs that I've found are on the official site, though they could surely use some polishing:

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation

The developers recommend reading the source as well, though if you have specific questions, I've found that the devs hang out and respond on both the IRC channel (**#twisted** on the freenode network) and the online mailing lists (There's [a general](http://twistedmatrix.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/twisted-python) and a [twisted-web specific](http://twistedmatrix.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/twisted-web) list)

As for blogs, there's at least the two below (both blogs are by twisted developers).  I bet if you asked this same question on the twisted-python mailing list, you'd get a much better and more comprehensive answer than I could possibly give.  :-)

http://oubiwann.blogspot.com/

http://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/

Comment: Worth noting that since this answer was written, a new edition of the book has been released, with updated content by a new author; https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449326110/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=1449326110&linkCode=as2&tag=twisted-sfconservancy-20

Answer (score 17):

I think you need to get your concepts right to start with.  I found this blog post to be helpful.

[Introduction to Asynchronous Programming and Twisted](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1209)

Comment: Definitely a good read, thanks. I wish I had it back then. My concepts might be a bit mis-worded because when I asked my question I was just starting out with networking/twisted. There are still some things which block and therefore need to be put into separate thread.

Comment: +1 Good Recommendation. Heard its a very good tutorial.

Comment: +1 too. Personally, found it more useful than any other source on web

Answer (score 3):

[Divmod](http://divmod.org/) has some medium sized projects which use Twisted and might make good additions to your reading list.  Additionally, the [Twisted Community Code in Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/tx) will give you a much longer list of Twisted-based projects to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Twisted Network Programming Essentials](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100322/) book to be a useful guide when first learning Twisted.  Although it is more of a Twisted "cookbook".  Some of its "recipes" are useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's an overview here: [The Twisted Network Framework](http://www.python.org/workshops/2002-02/papers/09/index.htm).

Bruce Eckel wrote a nice article that points out some of the weird names Twisted uses: [Grokking Twisted](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=156396). According to that article, there are some good examples in *The Python Cookbook*, 2nd Ed (O'Reilly).

Answer (score 1):

[This unofficial tutorial](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) is, in my opinion, the absolute definitive way to learn Twisted.

It contains step by step examples on how to use everything from super basic to advanced features. Everything is motivated by first doing it the hard way so that you really understand what problem each part of the Twisted solves.

I've used software based on Twisted for five years but it was only after working this tutorial that I now really understand it and use it from scratch for my own programs.

This is not self-promotion. I do not know the author of the tutorial to which I linked.