# Python twisted: where to start

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to start learning twisted for socket servers creation. I want to add some useful features (like auth, and maybe some other). Maybe someone can point me to  a good tutorial which will help me to start (+ maybe some other ideas)

Comment: You might want to also read answers to [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649029/where-can-i-find-good-python-twisted-framework-documentation-blog-entries-artic) which I asked.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Look here: [Twisted Web in 60 seconds](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/tag/sixty%20seconds). That's a group of blog posts describing step by step how to do lots of common stuff with Twisted, all written by Jean-Paul Calderone, the biggest contributor of Twisted. It's really where you should start.

After that, look at the Twisted [core documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) then refer to the [API](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/) and then into the [source code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-9.0.0/twisted).

Have fun!

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html now it in official docs

Comment: 60-seconds-series is so not where to start! Those are short recipes which don’t explain how to cook (with Twisted).

Comment: @Etienne Thanks for the post, however I agree with Robert Siemer. I just found Twisted and looking at the Twisted Web in 60 seconds thing is like trying to learn it by taking baby steps (more like Twisted Web in 60 days). I need to know how to "cook" :) and I am sure there is a more efficient tutorial out there...

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer, I didn't know the tutorial that Ben Hughes mentions, so the '60 seconds' posts were, for me at least, the easiest way to start with Twisted. I think there's still not much good tutorials for Twisted today, except those mention in this page.

Answer (score 70):

There's a great tutorial here - it's usually the one I send to new Twisty's :-)

http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327

Its worth remembering that Twisted programming is more of a thinking paradigm than a programming one. Also, it's worth doing away with the client server model too - in Twisted there's just one broker talking in either direction to another.

Take a look here after the above too:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-intro.html

Enjoy :-)

Comment: That's a nice list of tutorials. +1

Comment: krondo is really really awesome! TY