# Is there any thorough, broad documentation of Twisted that is better than the official site?

Tags: python, twisted

I've been looking at twisted for a while now. It looks interesting - it seems like a good way to leverage a lot of power when writing servers. Unfortunately, in spite of writing a few web servers using twisted.web (from reading other people's source and an extremely dated O'Reilly book) I've never really felt like I had reached an affinity with twisted... a level of understanding that actually *gave* me some of the power it seems like it has.

I think I need some good documentation to arrive at a better level of understanding - I simply don't have time to pore over the source, and other threads on SO have mentioned [twisted's official documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation), which is patchy at best, absent at worst, and occasionally very out of date.

Is there anything else out there that is more thorough, more forgiving, and more useful, or am I stuck with another classic, boring STFU and RTFM even though TFM is not helpful?

---

**Update**

In response to JP Calderone's comment that I'm just having a bitch, to some extent I guess I am, but I think the breadth of the question is valid considering the breadth and value of Twisted and the lack of obvious, thorough documentation. I have a few things in mind that I wanted to investigate, but I've been getting OK results just hacking things together and asking for specifics when a deeper, broader understanding is what I'm looking for is, in my mind, not helpful.

The contrast that immediately springs to mind is Django... I can read over the (very thorough) Django documentation and not necessarily know how to do everything it can do immediately, but I can get a really good overview of *how* I might do everything I needed to do, and know exactly where to look when the time comes.

Comment: If you were more specific about what you want to understand, someone might be able to refer you to some documentation which could give you that understanding.  Just saying you want to understand "Twisted" means that the best answer available is to read the Twisted documentation.  Clearly there's something specific you're after, but you haven't said what it is.

As this, this "question" comes across as an excuse to complain about Twisted's documentation, not a useful or interesting question.  Can you edit it to ask something more meaningful and possible to answer?

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to hear from one of the main contributors to the project! Yes, I guess I am having a bit of a vent but I think the question is still valid. Twisted seems pretty awesome and it has been very useful to me, but the documentation is a huge hole in a very worthy project. Is there any plan to get the documentation into shape (especially now that the web and web2 thing is sorted for good)? I'd help but I'm still (obviously) rather new to it. Also, "there isn't" is an acceptable answer if that's actually the case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to repeat what some of the answerers here have said (they're all good answers) in the hopes of providing an answer that is somewhat comprehensive.

1. While the included documentation is spotty in places, [the core documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/core/howto/index.html) contains several helpful and brief introductions to the basic concepts in Twisted.  Especially, see [Using Deferreds](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html), [Writing Clients](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html) and [Writing Servers](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html).
2. Also, the [API documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/moduleIndex.html) - especially the documentation in [interface modules](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.html) - is increasingly thorough and coherent with each subsequent release.
3. If you're interested in a higher-level description of Twisted's goals and design so you know how to approach some of this other documentation, [I co-authored a paper presented at USENIX 2003](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/lefkowitz/lefkowitz_html/index.html) with [Itamar Turner-Trauring](http://itamarst.org/).
4. [Twisted's FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) is also a bit meandering, but may help you with many stumbling blocks that people hit when working their way through introductory material.
5. The [O'Reilly book about Twisted](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100329) has some great examples which may further elucidate core concepts like Deferreds and the Reactor.
6. [Jean-Paul Calderone's "Twisted Web In 60 Seconds" tutorials](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/tag/sixty%20seconds) are a good introduction to the somewhat higher-level twisted.web, of course, but you will also see lots of useful patterns repeated throughout which may be useful to you in whatever application you're writing.
7. I have written a pair of articles on building-blocks used within Twisted, to [deal with the filesystem](http://glyf.livejournal.com/75142.html) and to [load plugins](http://glyf.livejournal.com/71805.html).
8. Last but *certainly* not least, [Dave Peticolas's modestly titled "Twisted Intro"](http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327) is a very comprehensive description, with diagrams and anecdotes, on the introductory material that so many people have difficulty with.

Please also note that all new functionality comes with new API (i.e. reference) documentation; we hope that this will make it more reasonable for people with technical writing skills to write documentation without having to struggle through even understanding what the method names mean.

Answer (score 7):

The [Twisted Intro](http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327) by [Dave Peticolas](http://krondo.com) is an *amazing* overview of Twisted from the ground up. It starts simple and then starts getting deeper and deeper while explaining everything along the way.

I've been using Twisted for years and found this intro to fill in all those gaps I was missing and shed light on the whole thing. Definitely worth your time to check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Check [Twisted Web in 60 seconds](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/50562.html) by Jean-Paul Calderone!

But, honestly, the Twisted's official documentation is not perfect but I'll not call it disgusting. There's a lot of valuable info in it.

Comment: Yep, fair cop. It was needlessly inflammatory. I've changed it, but not too much. It *is* pretty bad in places.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this previous post...

[Python twisted: where to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888139/python-twisted-where-to-start/1888748#1888748)

Answer (score 1):

There's the O'Reilly book [Twisted Network Programming Essentials](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100322/).

I have not read it, but the ToC looks nice enough.