# Twisted multiple protocols

Tags: python, networking, twisted

I am looking to learn twisted for a project I am working on. The project would require the server to respond to HTTP requests as well as other protocols over a TCP connection. Is twisted capable of handling multiple protocols at the same time? I want to use Twisted Web to help with the HTTP, but at the same time need to respond to TCP connections over other ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, yes. Twisted is a really good choice for this kind of needs, when multiple protocols need to work together.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888139/python-twisted-where-to-start/1888424#1888424) for great learning references.